# Maven use jar not found in local filesystem or public repository

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3

Similar to [Maven: Including jar not found in public repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355548/maven-including-jar-not-found-in-public-repository), I have a project that is built using maven and relies on a third party jar(just the jar is provided, not a maven project).

I currently store just include this jar in the project itself and point to it like:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.thirdparty</groupId>
     <artifactId>thirdparty</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/thirdparty.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This is nice, but I was wondering if it would be possible to store that thirdparty.jar in a central location, say S3 for instance, and then have that jar just be pulled from there when the project is being built?

Edit:
Aware that there are probably some third party services that can do this, however, I am not really interested in anything along those lines. Just looking to see if there is a pom xml tag or command line option that I appear to be overlooking.

Comment: That's what [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus) is for.

Comment: You may use a repository manager like nexus. This link would be helpful if you want to create repository manager - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882622/maven-private-remote-repository-setup

Comment: Another solution is Artifactory.  http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/  Bitnami also has a very simple windows install for it or a Linux VM https://bitnami.com/stack/artifactory

Comment: Thanks to those that have responded, not looking to do anything to fancy with this though, just looking to see if there is a simple tag or option in maven that I am overlooking.