# Maven doesn't see dependencies which are JAR files in a subfolder

Tags: java, maven

I have a project where I use Maven as the build tool.

In my `pom.xml` file I have these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.my.group1</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyArtifact1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.my.group2</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyArtifact2</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.my.group3</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyArtifact3</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Within the folder where I have my `pom.xml`, I also have a subfolder, `\external`. In this subfolder, I have the above listed artifacts as jars: `MyArtifact1-1.0.jar`, `MyArtifact2-1.1.jar`, `MyArtifact3-1.3.jar`.

The problem is that when I run `mvn install`, I get this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my.group4:sample-project:jar:20161207.3: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.my.group1:MyArtifact1:jar:1.0, com.my.group2:MyArtifact2:jar:1.1, com.my.group3:MyArtifact3:jar:1.3: Failure to find com.my.group1:MyArtifact1:jar:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

So far, I tied running this:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file  -Dfile=./external/MyArtifact1-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.my.group1 -DartifactId=MyArtifact1 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I tried the above for all 3 packages, but still it looks like it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: add a dependency to a jar by relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to include in the maven compilation `.jar` files you downloaded in your computer ?

Remember that Maven will try to get your dependencies from the local repository first (a folder in your computer) and from the global repositories later. If your dependencies (.jar) are not in those repositories, you will get an error message.

Here I give you some ideas/solutions:

1. **If the `.jar` files resulted from other maven projects**

   - If the `.jar` files are the product of other maven projects you created in your computer. You can [install the outputs of that project](https://maven.apache.org/run-maven/) in your local repository. Once they are installed, maven will find the dependencies locally.

     ```
     // in the other projects
     mvn clean install
     ```
   - If you have many local projects, you may [setup your own maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882622/maven-private-remote-repository-setup) to manage all your reusable components. Many companies [setup their own repository in their local network](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en). You can use software such as [Artifactory](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-debs/jfrog-artifactory-oss-deb/view)
     or [Nexus Repository Manager](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype). You can even built a [repository using your filesystem](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). Note that, in order to use these repositories, you have to configure them in the `pom.xml` file of your project.

     ```
     <project>
       ...
       <repositories>
         <repository>
           <id>my-internal-site</id>
           <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
         </repository>
       </repositories>
       ...
     </project>
     ```
2. **If the `.jar` files were downloaded from other websites**

   - Sometimes you need `.jar` files that exist in global maven repositories. You may try first to search in these repositories. You can go to sites such as [MVN repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) to search or browse the existing packages in the repositories. If you find the dependencies you need, you can obtain too the required dependency to include in the `pom.xml`.
   - If the `.jar` files does not exist in any repository, you can [install the file in your local repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html). There is [a tutorial in the Heroku's devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies) and another one in [Mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/). You must pick a groupId-artifactId-version for the file, install the file and add the dependency to the `pom.xml` of the project.
     Note that, if the `.jar` was not created using maven, you must provide all the parameters

     ```
     mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
         -DgroupId=your.groupId \
         -DartifactId=your-artifactId \
         -Dversion=version \
         -Dpackaging=jar \
         -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
     ```

     If the `.jar` was generated with Maven, that file will include their own `pom.xml` with metadata. If you use Maven 2.5+, you do not need to provide the groupId-artifactId and version.

     ```
     mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
         -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
     ```
   - There is another option. You can use the `system` scope with a local `systemPath`. However, I think this solution requires that people keep the library in the same location for all the developers, or requires to include the `.jar` file in the project/code repository. Using a repository is a better idea.

     ```
     <dependency>
         <artifactId>..</artifactId>
         <groupId>..</groupId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/dependency.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether these jars present in your local repository.

You can find it's location from your maven **setting.xml** file , if not mentioned there then it will take the default path i.e. **.m2** folder inside c drive.

You need to check first whether these jars are present there or not. If not, then either you need to copy those in proper folder structure or you can install those jars on your local firing below command :

```
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id>  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is:

- use a Maven Repository manager such as Nexus
- configure Maven to use a [Single Repository Group](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Maven+Repositories#MavenRepositories-ConfiguringApacheMaven)
- configure proxy repos to other Maven Repositories as needed and add them to the group you specified in your settings file (see previous step)
- if not already available, configure a repo for 3rd party libs in your repository manager and add it to the group you specified in your settings file (see previous step)
- if your dependencies are not available from any repo, then add them to your 3rd party repo
- remove all JARs from the source code

Comment: Can I solve my problem without using an external repository manager?

Comment: Maybe, but as you see, it quickly becomes tricky, especially when you want reproducable builds (on the CI, fellow developer). Using a Maven Repository manager is the recommended way for reproducable and stable Maven builds.