# Apache MAVEN: How can I specify a jar dependency from a non standard repository without a pom in the repo?

Tags: maven

I am newbie to Maven, My question described below:

I have a jar file in the following repo:
http://www.repo.com/custom/path/Jarfile-0.1.0.jar

I have added the repository to the pom file as follows

```
<repository>
<url>http://www.repo.com/custom/path </url>
<id>Custom_repo</id>
</repository>
```

I have set the dependency in the pom file as follows:

```
<dependancy>
<groupId>XXX<groupId>
<artifactId>Jarfile</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
</depandancy>
```

when I do a compile 'mvn compile' The output is:

```
Downloading: http:/www.repo.com/custom/path/XXX/Jarfile/0.1.0/Jarfile-0.1.0.pom
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project X: could not resolve dependencies for project ... could not transfer artifact from Custom_repo...
```

There are two issues:

1. The path(consisting of groupid, artifactid and version) **/XXX/Jarfile/0.1.0/** gets appended to the Custom_repo which I do not want - how can I get rid of it?
2. I want to get the jar file and not a **.pom** file. What can be done to get the jar? (I know about the <systemPath> - but that is taking the jar from the system - not from repo)

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven repo is a little bit more complex than a simple jar. You can try to install a reposotory server such as **Nexus**.

http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/

See also this post
[Maven Internal Repository, Is it Really This Hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955526/maven-internal-repository-is-it-really-this-hard)

You can also **install** the jar file **on local repository** through:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>
```

**Maven Dependency Search Sequence**

- Step 1 - Search dependency in local repository, if not found, move to
  step 2 else if found then do the further processing.
- Step 2 - Search dependency in central repository, if not found and
  remote repository/repositories is/are mentioned then move to step 4
  else if found, then it is downloaded to local repository for future
  reference.
- Step 3 - If a remote repository has not been mentioned, Maven simply
  stops the processing and throws error (Unable to find dependency).
- Step 4 - Search dependency in remote repository or repositories, if
  found then it is downloaded to local repository for future reference
  otherwise Maven as expected stop processing and throws error (Unable
  to find dependency).